# How can I find users who have earned gold badges for their great answers?

Tags: feature-request, badges

How can I find users who have earned gold badges for their great answers?

Answer (score 4):

On the [Great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) badges page. You can also go to the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page and click on any of the badges to see who has received them.

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer.

Comment: @Gamecat Please consider following the advice, "If you are going to edit a post, make sure you’re substantively improving it. Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the source of much friction. For example, don’t bother changing “its” to “it’s” unless you have several other edits to make in the same post. There has to be a legitimate case that your edit made multiple changes transforming the post from good to great — or at least substantively improving it." blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the badges page and click on the badge, it shows you who it was recently awarded to.